# Access previous version of a visited webpage?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

I opened a page in Firefox and came back hours later. I reloaded the page (to see if something new was added), but had to notice that something got deleted instead.

Is there a way to see the previous version of the page? Does it get saved in the browser cache? Or will the cached version be removed as soon as I reload the page (and the content changes)?

(If I had expected a deletion, I would have opened the same page in a different tab instead of reloading the page in the same tab.)

Comment: have you considered http://archive.org/web/ ?

Comment: @Ash: Good suggestion, but in this particular case the page/URL was published only minutes after I opened it (and the deletion probably happened some minutes after that), so the *Internet Archive* crawler was not yet there.

Comment: did you do f5 to refresh ? The mere existence of ctrl + f5 to throw out the cashed version and request a new copy from server tells that cashed version  will not be thrown as soon as you refreshed the page.

Comment: @unor - In the case you describe the cache files have already been replaced by Firefox with the newer version.

Comment: @Ash: I switched to the address bar (*Ctrl* + *l*) and hit *Enter*.

Comment: try Google's web cache : *http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://example.com/*

Comment: @Ash: Unfortunately, not crawled yet. I assume that no web service (except for the site itself, that is) has a copy (because the page was newly published and it’s not a well-known one). So a solution would need to work locally with my cache or something.

Answer (score 2):

The cached version does not necessarily get removed as soon as you hit refresh. The mere existence of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd> to throw out the cached version and request a new copy from server tells that cached version will not be removed as soon as you refreshed the page.

In your case, the cached version from Google or [Waybackmachine](http://archive.org/web/) would not be helpful as they might not even have cached the page in concern.  Your best bet may be to inspect your cache with [CacheViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer/) or any similar software to find something useful.

You can access the cached version for any page that has been saved by Google with this:

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:*example site*
```